# on new system sudo apt install nodejs not working

Tags: nodejs

[image]

I want to install node version 10.16.3

- so  i am trying to install using nvm but my node js showing me this error

```
Command 'nodejs' not found, but can be installed with:

sudo apt install nodejs
```

i already install nodejs still i am getting this error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have already installed NodeJS. This is indicate by the following output on your screenshot:

> ```
> nodejs is already the newest version (12.22.1-1nodesource1).
> ```

Its executable is `node` and not `nodejs`.

So to check its version you have to use the below command:

```
node --version
```

to get output like

> ```
> v12.22.1
> ```

Comment: i want to install 10.16.3 any idea how to install it ? @Norbert

Comment: Then at first you should remove nodejs v12 with its repository. For v10 use `wget -qO- https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_10.x | sudo -E bash -`. And then `sudo apt-get install nodejs=10.24.1-deb-1nodesource1`. But please note that "Node.js 10.x is no longer actively supported!".

Comment: in place of `10.24.1` i have to replace it with `10.16.3` ? @Norbert

Comment: 10.16.3 is not available. But please note that 10.19 is available from [official repository](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/nodejs). So you can use it instead.

Comment: ok thank you @Norbet :)

Answer (score 0):

try

```
sudo apt remove nodejs
```

then

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install nodejs
```